# Issue with IE7 display:table in menu

Tags: css

I Wrote a menu style which is working fine in IE8,FF3.6,GC7. Now the problem is, my boss want it to work even on IE7. I really tried hard to make it work on IE7, but unable to get the same look.

menu.css

```
a{outline:none;}

.menu {
margin:0;
display:table;
padding:0;
white-space:nowrap;
width:958px;
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
height: 30px;
background: transparent url("../images/menubg.jpg") repeat-x top left;
border-bottom:4px solid #92C4E9;
border-right:2px solid #005D91;
border-left:2px solid #005D91;
}
.menu ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table-row;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.menu ul li{
display:table-cell;
border-right:1px solid #005D91;
border-left:1px solid #005D91;
}
.menu ul a{
display:block;
padding:12px 5px 0 5px;
text-decoration:none;
height:26px;
margin: 0 3px 0 3px;    
color:#ffffff;  
}
.menu ul a:hover{
margin: 0 3px 0 3px;    
background:transparent url("../images/menubgover.jpg") repeat-x top left;

}
.menu li ul
{   
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
display:none;
position:absolute;
background-color:#15375f;
filter: alpha(opacity=85); 
-moz-opacity:0.85; 
-khtml-opacity: 0.85;
opacity: 0.85;

}
.menu li:hover ul
{
margin:0px;
padding: 15px 15px 0px 20px;
text-align:left;
line-height:0px;
display:block;
color:#fff;
}
.menu li li
{
list-style:none;
display:list-item;
border-right:0px;
border-left:0px;
padding:0px;
}
.menu li li a
{color:#92C4E9; text-decoration:none; padding:0; margin:0px; font-weight:normal;
}
.menu li li a:hover
{color:#92C4E9; text-decoration:underline; background:none; padding:0; margin:0px; font-weight:normal;}

.present{margin: 0 3px 0 3px;background:transparent url("../images/menubgover.jpg") repeat-x top left;}
```

Comment: *sidenote:* padding or margin with 0 value has no unit.

Answer (score 7):

IE7 doesn't support `display:table`, so you have to rebuild the menu in a different way.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Maybe because you have not provided any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the refusal of IE to support display: table et al is the main cause of most CSS layout hack out there. It's really sad how one company has been holding back web development progress =(

edit: an alternative might be to use display: table for all sane browsers and a [clearfix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) hack for IE. You could of course just use clearfix for all browsers, but display: table etc renders much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Ie8 actually doesn't support any of the table display properties only firefox and a few other browsers do

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

I would just try using display:block

Comment: Yes, you are right. Some times it even not working in IE8. I just learned css on net only to build this menu. I really dont have adequate grip on css to get the required look. fortunately I managed to work it out with above css. Please guggest me way of getting it. Thank you very much.

Comment: whats the HTML look like and what kind of menu effect are you trying to achieve

Comment: Incorrect: `display: block` does not behave like `display: table`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use `display:inline-block`

Comment: Incorrect. `display: inline-block` is not supported in IE7. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display