# Image is not clickable inside anchor only in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, haslayout

Html Structure

```
<a>
   <span>   <!-- Span has width & height -->
   <img>
   </span>
   <span> Some text <span>
</a>
```

Anchor is not clickable only in IE7, I know the issue happens because of hasLayout, if we remove height & width of the span, it will work fine.

But I need to make it work with out removing height &  width.

**EDIT:** You can fiddle with an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb

Comment: I have the same problem: the following image is not clickable in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/

Comment: @Tomas--I posted an answer that should meet your needs.

Comment: see my answer and let me know if i am lagging somewhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### CSS Only Solution

Tomas-[I modified your fiddle into a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/9/). I changed your code to use a `span` inside the `a` tag because it is invalid to have a standard block level element (a `div`) in an inline element (an `a` tag). Giving the `a` tag layout (I used `inline-block`) and then setting a `position:relative` on that `span` with a `z-index: -1` pushes the `span` "below" the `a` tag and makes IE7 recognize the `a` tag as active again. Below is the modified code used in my fiddle. You might want to set up a more generic class name than my `ie7AFix` (you probably will also want to just target IE7 for those CSS properties that are necessary for it only). I assume you are varying the `width` and `height` by images, and hence why you have those as inline styling.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="ie7AFix">
  <span style="width:222px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/aviff/photos/scaled/P000137_220x148.jpg" style="width:220px; height: 148px;">
  </span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a.ie7AFix {
    display: inline-block; /*needs to set hasLayout; zoom: 1, etc.*/
}

.ie7AFix span {
    border: solid #666 4px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    line-height: 0; /*this made it "cross browser" eliminating extra bottom space*/
}

.ie7AFix img { border: 1px solid red; }
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/22/)** with `line-height` added to make "cross browser" if one does not want to target IE7 only. I kept the `width` and `height` in the `span` html above, only because the original question (by both gviswanathan and Tomas) requested it. If you don't need to set the dimensions on the `span` for some reason, but are simply trying to do a double border on the image, then [thirtydot's answer given in the comment's below](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Zc2cg/) is much simpler.

Comment: Scott, how great!! It really works with CSS only! Few questions: 1) why do you use the position and z-index? I tried to remove it and it works in IE7. 2) I tried to remove the width/height for <span> tag but it makes small padding at the bottom in FF/Opera/Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/14/. I set the dimensions for the div (now span) tag because of [IE7 problem with display:table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4204954), which is not needed now with your solution. Thanks again, this is a great answer, thanks for fixing code validity!

Comment: Sorry, 1) is irrelevant, removing position & z-index [doesn't work in IE7](http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/17/) (I accidentally switched to IE8..). So the only remaining question is about removing the span's width&height, because your solution is so great that it is possible to remove it in IE7! http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/19/ Interestingly, this only works in IE7! IE8/FF/Opera/Chrome displays a space below the image.

Comment: @Tomas-I kept the width/height of the span because you had it (so I assumed you wanted it). If it is not necessary for your purposes, then by all means, eliminate the unneeded mark-up. Glad it works.

Comment: Scott, I needed the width&height only because it was necessary before you posted your solution. Now it seems it can be removed, but there is still the [problem with the remaining space](http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/19/).

Comment: @Tomas--well, I did mention in my post that I would only target these changes to IE7 css (and let the other browsers not have the "fix"). However, if you insist on having a single css for all, then it appears to be a `line-height` issue and is resolved [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/22/).

Comment: Thanks Scott, you are guru! @gviswanathan, this is the ultimate answer to our problem, **I recommend to accept this answer!**

Comment: @Tomas: It seems to me like you're overcomplicating this a bit. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Zc2cg/. It seems the same to me, but simpler.

Comment: @thirtydot, `vertical-align: top` - another trick! `line-height` to `<a>` doesn't work in this case... OMG. Nice, thanks.

Comment: @thirtydot--I agree with you. The whole premise behind my answer was the initial requirement (both of gviswanathan and Tomas) of having a `span` with a `width` set within the `a` tag. If that is not needed for some other reason, then the added gymnastics that I show are not necessary.

Comment: Scott & @thirtydot, the "gymnastic" with `<a><span><img>` was because of the initial problems with IE7! But thanks to Scott the code can now simplify a lot! And thanks to you thirtydot for final simplification.

Comment: @Tomas: No problem. You were almost a victim of the ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 5):

With jQuery, the following will force all links to work, and have the 'pointer' cursor:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a')
        .click(function () {        
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        })
        .hover(function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });

});
```

I've tested this simulating IE7 with IE8 in compatibility view mode, but can't guarantee it will for IE7 on its own.

You may want to apply this more selectively -- I suspect that, as is, this might slow down older browser performance -- in which case apply a class (like `<a href='myClass'>`) to all links that are broken this way, and just change `$('a')` to `$('.myClass')`

Comment: this is the only fix that really works in IE7 (unfortunatelly using javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/3/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the HTML5 shim? It helps a lot with issues that are caused by [hasLayout](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEaL.html).

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: good tip, thanks - but does it help if my page is in HTML 4.01?

Comment: Yeah should do, I don't think it ignores pages that have a non-HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 1):

Just take out the SPAN from the IMG. The IMG element can be styled with a class just like any other element, therefore you don't need a span around it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah [another hasLayout quirk](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEaL.html)

it's not possible to achieve in IE7 and still retain the width of the span, if you could show what you're trying to achieve in a JS fiddle perhaps we could help, find a way around it e.g. and this is only a guess,  putting the width on the `anchor` with some padding would help create a completely clickable area and still allow a "caption" span to be restrained if that's what you're after..

*Example workaround not a fix*

**CSS:**

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff0; 
  max-width: 50px; 
  padding: 10px; 
  text-align: center;
}

img {border: 0; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;}
span {line-height: 1.5;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">
   <img width="50" height="50" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" alt="">
   <span>Some text and even longer</span>
</a>
```

The above is only a thought, and if it's not what you're after, then please provide a sample [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I am not ensure that standard width & height will pertain for the image in runtime.

Thats why i need to give the wrapper width & height to act as image container.

Image will align top, and text will align at bottom

Answer (score 0):

give the following CSS rules to the a element:

```
{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a problem is that because you didn't define `href="#"` inside your `<a>` TAG So, put `href="#"` inside your `<a>` TAG. Write like this:

```
<a href="#">
   <span>   <!-- Span has width & height -->
   <img>
   </span>
   <span> Some text <span>
</a>
```

Comment: Isnt it like that for example purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap anchor tag inside Div or Span. Its working in IE7.

This way is wrong..?

Comment: Can you provide an example in jsfiddle? Feel free to start with mine.

Answer (score 0):

From your post I think u wanted a clickable image with span info text !! I hope this will help u ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/ajinkyax/v5KH5/3/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="imgLink">
<img src="http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/aviff/photos/scaled/P000137_220x148.jpg" />
<span>Info text about image</span> </a>
```

CSS:

```
.imgLink {display: block; width: 200px; text-align: center;}​
```

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle for code and demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/29/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rxcAb/29/embedded/result/

Perfectly working in IE7, IE8, FF, Chrome, Safari.

No changes in code: See below

```
<a href=http://www.google.com/>
<div class="gal_image" style="width:222px; height: 150px;">
        <img src="http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/aviff/photos/scaled/P000137_220x148.jpg" style="width:220px; height: 148px;">
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is:

```
<p>
 <span><img></span>
 <span> Some text <span>
 <a></a>
<p>

p { display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; }
a { display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: #fff; opacity: .0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; }`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like:

```
<a name="link1" href="somelink.php">
<div class="somediv"><img src="image.jpg" class="somestyle"></div>
</a>
```

Simply add a style property to the anchor like this:

```
<a name="link1" href="somelink.php" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">
```

This will make the div and everything inside of it clickable in IE7+ and firefox & chrome.