# IE does not recognize href buttons

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Do you have any idea why IE does not recognize any of these buttons below as a link at all?

```
<a href="#zanas" class="content-loader"><div id="zanas"></div></a>
<a href="#dizain" class="pics_holders"><div id="dizain"></div></a>
<a href="#izkustvo"><div id="izkustvo"></div></a>
<a href="#kontakti" class="content-loader"><div id="kontakti"></div></a>
```

also check out the site (the buttons are located on the lamp's shape) - http://lambev-design.com/

**Update:** I saw that the elements have to contain something (the empty spaces did not work), and knowing that the divs are located in 4 different places rather to create a span tags I chose to simply put an images in those divs with opacity as 0 but i do't know if that is a CrossBrowser command and if will work everywhere).

Comment: according to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fttyh/) only IE7 makes problems... see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess because `<a><div></div></a>` markup is not valid (well, not only, the second reason is IE itself...). Try to replace the `<div>`with `<span>` and add some CSS rules:

```
a.content-loader span { 
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
a.content-loader { display: inline-block; }
```

This strange fiddling helps to solve the IE7 issue and should be cross-browser valid. See http://jsfiddle.net/Fttyh/3/ which works in IE7 (unlike [the original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fttyh/)).

I had very [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5735158/684229) recenty and I adopted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9969886/684229) to your problem :-) so refer there for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help you but i can not set 4 differend divs (each of them located in certain place) in one class, you can check out the site. I have also faund a simple decision :), but i don't know if will work...

Answer (score 0):

try adding the `id="..."` into the a-tag:

```
<a href="#dizain" class="pics_holders" id="dizain"></a>
```

dont know if that helps but I think I did it before...

Comment: This doesn't make a difference.

Comment: May God bless you, for your help, no matter your answer did not worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A tags doesn't make Divs in IE, as a workaround you could write this:

```
<a href="#zanas" class="content-loader"><div onclick="window.location.hash='#zanas'" id="zanas"></div></a>
```